# Bar and line graphs overlaying on same figure, containing groups, and by another group

Tags: data-visualization, stata

I am attempting to create a figure that essentially has a bar graph corresponding to one group and a line graph for another group, but where there are two groups within each of the formerly described groups. I have tried various ways of using twoway and binscatter but have not been able to achieve what I would like.

I am including a picture of what I would like to create:

[image]

(On the y-axis is "cost" which both the line graphs and bar graphs refer to. From a data visualization standpoint I would personally use either 4 line graphs or even 4 bar graphs, but 2 lines, and 2 sets of bars are what is desired).

I imagine it might take some reshaping, but it might not. If anyone has any leads, I would definitely appreciate it. If color could be left to the user's desire, that would be even better. Although I think the data is shaped so that one could create the graph "automatically" by referring to the categories, it might be possible to reshape the data and use county-year as the categorical variable.

The code to develop the dataset (thanks to Nick Cox for developing a superior version of my example code):

```
clear
set seed 1234 
set obs 16
g year = cond(_n > 8, 2010, 2000) 
bysort year: g country = cond(_n > 4, "China", "USA")  
bysort year country : gen month = _n 
g cost = runiform(0, 100)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand which "group" is to be shown by bars and which by lines. Your legend doesn't seem to help. Two things are red and two things are blue.... The "what is desired" seems to hint that you are under instructions (to produce a design that seems weird to the point of graphical perversity to me without a backing story).

Comment: Sorry Nick. I think it would have been easier if I made it clear that the colors for "2000 USA" and "2000 China" different from one another.  In my drawing, the colors for USA are supposed to be different shades from those for China, reflecting that they are speaking of a similar quantity (cost) but just for a different country. The red-blue or light red - light blue difference is supposed to capture the 10 year difference. Furthermore the bars correspond to the USA values while one's eyes would track the lines to see values for China.

Comment: That's too subtle for me and very optimistic about whoever is going to read this graph. You may need some combination `twoway bar ... || line ...` but I am variously reluctant and unable to suggest precise code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to understand what you wanted to create. See the example code below:

```
//Trick 1
separate cost,by(year)

//Trick 2
gen month1 = month - 0.12
gen month2 = month + 0.12

twoway (bar cost2000 month1 if country == "USA", barw(0.2) color(red)) || ///
(bar cost2010 month2 if country == "USA", barw(0.2)  color(ltblue))  || ///
(line cost2000 month if country == "China",lcolor(cranberry) lwidth(0.8) ) || ///
(line cost2010 month if country == "China",lcolor(blue) lwidth(0.8)), ///
legend(order(1 "2000" "USA" 2 "2010" "USA" 3 "2000" "CHN" 4 "2010" "CHN") row(1)) ///
ytitle("Cost")
```

The resulting graph looks like:
[image]

Here are the two tricks that you can find from Nick Cox's previous posts: [Trick 1](https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2006-01/msg00705.html); [Trick 2](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1563110-side-by-side-bars-for-twoway-bar-graph).